# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: > org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelException

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

i use play framework,and i want to run on intellij
this is my configure
[image]

but when i run enterprise,the error is

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56744', transport:
>   'socket' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelException  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 6 more
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56744',
>   transport: 'socket' Exception in thread "main"  Process finished with
>   exit code 1

how to solve it?
i add netty jar,but the problem still exists
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you show your module settings for the `enterprise` module? Especially the "Dependencies" tab?

Comment: @JanThomä i have added jar image